# How do I make sure my script is running on Open Shift?

Tags: android, node.js, postgresql, openshift

So, I have a restful webservice made on Node.js to lookup on a Postgresql DB. I've uploaded it on OpenShift. I'm trying to access it via Android but it doesn't work. Is there anyway I can make sure my script is running? I've already included it on the package.json. Also, is there anyway to actually see the script running to keep track of eventual errors?

Comment: If you have configured RHC you can check there

Comment: I got it. I had to replace the server.js filename with my script in the package.json file. Putting it as a "scripts.start" object didn't work.

Comment: Thats cool, why dont u answer yourself and accept it so that other people who might having the same probelm can refer to your poat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had to replace the server.js filename with my script in the package.json file. Putting it as a "scripts.start" object didn't work.